# Sum of arguments for inverse of function f

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given the function is given as $x=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and corresponding $f(x)= \{4,0,-1,4,3,2\}$

Find the sum of the arguments for which $f^{-1}$ is defined

Here for $f^{-1}$(4) it has two values 1 and 4 so should it be considered? I am bit confused in this step.

Comment: $f^{-1}(4)$ is not defined but $ f^{-1}(\{4\})=\{1,4\}$.

Comment: Remember that $f^{-1}$ can be define if and only every number from the starting space it has a unique image in the ending space, here $f^{-1}(4)$ cannot be defined (it would have been 1 and 4 which is impossible !)                                  Remark : $f^{-1}$ is defined on ${x}$ if and only if $f^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton.

Comment: @EDX Thanks but here what are the arguments for which ${f^-1}$ is defined

Comment: y=0,−1,3,2 are the argument for which $f^{-1}$ is defined

Comment: @EDX Got it thanks